# java moving jlabel with picture inside other jlabel bounds

Tags: java, image, jlabel, move

Im programing game in netbeans in java 
I have 2 jlabels

first jLabel1 I want to move around because it has  figure picture i usualy use jLabel1.setLocation(x,y);
// problem is that this focuses on whole frame and starts coordinates from upper-left corner of the frame

I want coordinating within jLabel2 wich has picture inside so that coordinate 0,0 will be on upper-left of the jlabel2 (upper-left of the jLabel2 picture)
Is this possible and how

Tnx for answers

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you imply that you have a `JLabel` within a `JLabel`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

first i get

int x=jLabel2.getX();
int y=jLabel2.getY();

so now my start coordiante will be at coordinates of jlabel2

and then i just add desired x and y related to the picture

int desired_x=20;
int desired_y=20;

jLabel1.setLocation(x+desired_x,y+desired_y);